# Sql cast 'dd-mmm-yyy' to datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have two tables

- in `temp` table I have `[infoDate] [nvarchar](255) NULL`
- in `info` table I have `[infoDate] [datetime] NULL`

There are values like `'17-JUL-14'` in `temp` table

I want to insert `info` table from `temp` table.

```
insert into info (infoDate) 
   select (infoDate) 
   from temp
```

I tried following queries, but not possible to convert string to datetime

```
select convert(varchar, '17-JUL-14', 105)

SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,'17-JUL-14',6),'-',' ')

SELECT SUBSTRING('17-JUL-14',1,2)+' '+SUBSTRING('17-JUL-14',4,3)+' '+SUBSTRING('17-JUL-14',8,2)
```

This query worked

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,SUBSTRING('17-JUL-14',1,2)+' '+SUBSTRING('17-JUL-14',4,3)+' '+SUBSTRING('17-JUL-14',8,2),106)
```

but now, how can insert into `info` table ?

```
 insert into info (infoDate) 
    select 
       (CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(infoDate, 1, 2) + ' ' + 
                          SUBSTRING(infoDate, 4, 3) + ' ' + 
                          SUBSTRING(infoDate, 8, 2), 106)) 
    from temp
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your current insert query

Comment: Simply do a `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '17-JUL-14')` this should convert it to datetime

Comment: What happens when you try?   Do you get an error?

Comment: I got this error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify the code.

**Before**

```
insert into info (infoDate) 
    select 
       (CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(infoDate, 1, 2) + ' ' + 
                          SUBSTRING(infoDate, 4, 3) + ' ' + 
                          SUBSTRING(infoDate, 8, 2), 106)) 
    from temp
```

**After**

```
insert into info (infoDate) 
    select 
       (CONVERT(datetime2, infoDate, 106))
    from temp
```

Comment: It did not work, I am getting "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." error

Comment: Be sure to verify you are working with non-corrupt data in your temp table. That might be the source of the problem.